# Flutter - Firebase IOS Emulator WhiteScreen when including options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform

Tags: flutter, firebase

When adding the options to the initialise Command the emulator starts with a WhiteScreen.
The android emulator only works when these options are included.

`await Firebase.initializeApp( options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform, );`

When deleting the options I no longer get a white screen but FireBase throws exceptions when trying to authorise.